# Did Saitama's serious punch physically touch this character?

Tags: one-punch-man

In the finale of season 1, did Saitama's serious punch physically touch Lord Boros or was it just the after-effect of the punch that hit Boros?

Comment: To know the answer you'd have to watch the thing. Have you seen it? I mean if you can see Saitama punch the guy, then yes. If not, then no. It should be pretty obvious. Why are you asking?

Comment: @Hakase I watched the whole episode. It wasn't obvious to me. They show Saitama moving towards Boros and then the scene cuts out.

Comment: Then we don't know!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, it was simply the shockwave that hit him.

[image: the shockwave]

Boros hits Saitama with his Trump card from far away and Saitama does the same with his own trump card from far. So, it's just the shockwave from Saitama's punch.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

This was right after Saitama's serious punch and Boros's final attack collided. Hence, we can clearly see there is sufficient amount of the distance between the two and there was no physical contact.